# Is there in stl or boost thread safe structure for inter thread communication - with behavior like queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, stl

I have game and I have two threads , one generates custom class and needs to store that (I put to push that in queue but I am not sure if that is thread safe, first thread generates every 50ms new instance, and second can read faster if there is any or slower  - speed changes over time) . Another thread uses if queue is not empty , pop first and calculates some things. Is there any data structure thread safe for this problem in stl or boost ?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `std::queue` or any similar container will not be thread safe. If you want your access (push/pop) to be thread-safe, while using std::queue, you should use `boost::mutex` or a similar mechanism to lock before each access. You can look at `boost::shared_mutex` if you need immutable reads from more than one thread (not sure you need that based on what you described).

Apart from that, you can take a look at `boost::interprocess::message_queue`, as someone has already mentioned -> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp for the most recent version of boost.

Moreover, there is the concept of lock-free queues [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm). I cannot provide an example of such implementation but I am sure you can find some if you google around.

Comment: Also [boost::lockfree](http://tim.klingt.org/boost_lockfree/) (not part of boost yet).